# How to get rid of "numpy.ndarray" has no attribute split?

Tags: python, numpy, split, attributeerror, numpy-stl

I have try to edit one stl file. With regards to this, I read the stl file using numpy-stl. Now, when I try to split the lines present in it, it shows me an error as:

**'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'split'**

How to overcome this? Below is the code.

```
import numpy as np
import stl
from stl import mesh


lines = mesh.Mesh.from_file('mesh.stl')
count = 0
for line in lines:
   if line.split()[0] == "solid":
      repl = line.split()[1]
      print(repl)
```

Any leads will be appreciated.

Regards,
Sunag R A.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you obtain an ndarray object where you apply split.

Just convert it to a string (with *tostring()* method) before doing it, and it will work.

Comment: Could you please shed a light on how to do that? I mean how to convert ndarray object to string?

Comment: I have edited the question. Just use line.tostring()

Comment: *edtited the answer

Comment: Thank you @Lore.

I did try it now, it says "Mesh object has no attribute 'tostring'.

Am I missing something in this?

Comment: Use line.tostring() not lines.tostring()

Answer (score 0):

simply use `str(line)` instead `tostring(line)` method